# substr first two letters match in array not working

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string which is being generated from an input field and i want to check the first two characters and see if they are found in an array. If they are I want a message to appear.

Can anyone explain why this isn't working please?

```
$i = strtoupper($_POST['postcode']);
    $ep = array("AB", "BT", "GY", "HS", "IM", "IV", "JE", "PH", "KW");

    if (isset($i)) {

    if(substr($i, 0, 2) === in_array($i, $ep)) {
        echo "Sorry we don't deliver to your postcode";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Probably becose a post code's letters come at the end instead of the beginning.

Comment: Because `substr()` method returns **the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters**, and `in_array()` method returns **boolean**

Comment: `if(in_array(substr($i, 0, 2), $ep))`

Comment: Try using [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: be careful in assuming how a postcode looks like. This varies heavily throughout the countries..

Comment: Hi Jeff, can you explain further please? The postcodes I'm entering are all UK based

Comment: then your site/code is limited to UK. If this is the case, then you're fine. In most other countries in europe there are no 2 letters at the beginning of postcodes. Not to speak about asia, america, ...

Comment: Yes, the site is limited to the UK only so I guessed doing it like this wouldn't be a problem. I understand this is a basic solution but can you provide any links to more advanced ways of doing this? So the code wouldn't be limited to UK, if it did expand?

Comment: UK postcode validation is tricky enough.  There are some non-geographic ones, as well as overseas territories to consider.  Find a tried and tested validation library, and tune to your delivery requirements.  Concern yourself with global delivery as and when the need arrives!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand how `in_array` works, check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for more details.

The following code is an improved way to check if the given post code is valid

```
<?php
/**
 * Check if the given post code is valid
 * @param string $postcode 
 * @return boolean
 */
function is_valid_postcode( $postcode = '' )
{
    $ep = array("AB", "BT", "GY", "HS", "IM", "IV", "JE", "PH", "KW");
    $postcode = strtoupper( $postcode );
    return in_array( $postcode , $ep );
}

if( isset( $_POST['postcode'] ) ){

    // Remove unwanted spaces if they're there
    $postcode = trim( $_POST['postcode'] );

    // Extract only the first two caracters
    $postcode = substr($postcode, 0, 2 );

    // Check if the submitted post code is valid
    if( !is_valid_postcode( $postcode ) ){
        echo "Sorry we don't deliver to your postcode";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Karkouch, thank you for your detailed answer :) I've tried this method but the trim() isn't working correctly. The message only appears if i have a space now? If i remove the trim it works. Any suggestions?

Comment: From the doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php, trim removes any white spaces from the beginning and the end of any given string.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of [in_array](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is wrong. Change

```
if(substr($i, 0, 2) === in_array($i, $ep)) {
  echo "Sorry we don't deliver to your postcode";
}
```

to

```
if(in_array(substr($i, 0, 2), $ep)) {
  echo "Sorry we don't deliver to your postcode";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

```
$i = strtoupper($_POST['postcode']);
$ep = array("AB", "BT", "GY", "HS", "IM", "IV", "JE", "PH", "KW");

if (isset($i)) {

    $i = substr($i, 0, 2);

    if(in_array($i, $ep)) {
        echo "Sorry we don't deliver to your postcode";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Is there an argument for using it this way as apposed to the other answers?

Comment: Nothing as such. You can adapt whichever you like. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(in_array(substr($i, 0, 2), $ep)) {
    echo "Sorry we don't deliver to your postcode";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$i = strtoupper($_POST['postcode']);
    $ep = array("AB", "BT", "GY", "HS", "IM", "IV", "JE", "PH", "KW");

    if (isset($i)) {
    $i = substr($i, 0, 2);
    if(in_array($i, $ep)) {
        echo "Sorry we don't deliver to your postcode";
    }   
}
```